# How can I detect monospace fonts in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe4

How can I detect monospace fonts in Delphi?

`TFont.Pitch` should be `fpFixed` I think, but it does not work for me with Delphi XE4:

```
var
  Font: TFont;
begin
  Font := TFont.Create;
  Font.Name := 'Courier New';
  if Font.Pitch = fpFixed then
    ShowMessage('Monospace Font!');
  ...
```

`Font.Pitch` based on `GetObject` of the WinAPI. It should return in `lfPitchAndFamily` `FIXED_PITCH`, but I always get `DEFAULT_PITCH` for all fonts (also for Arial).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `GetObject` really returns `DEFAULT_PITCH`. But you can get true value through enumeration of fonts with needed name:

```
function EnumFontsProc(var elf: TEnumLogFont;
                       var tm: TNewTextMetric;
                       FontType: Integer;
                       Data: LPARAM): Integer; stdcall;
begin;
  Result := Integer(FIXED_PITCH = (elf.elfLogFont.lfPitchAndFamily and FIXED_PITCH));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button13Click(Sender: TObject);
begin;
  if EnumFontFamilies(Canvas.Handle,
                      PChar('Courier New'),
                      @EnumFontsProc,0) then
     Caption := 'Fixed'
  else
     Caption := 'Variable';
end;
```

**Edit:** In newer Delphi versions `EnumFontFamilies` function is described as returning `Integer` result (in accordance with [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enumfontfamiliesa)), as Andreas Rejbrand noticed in comments, so result should be treated as:

```
 if EnumFontFamilies(Canvas.Handle,
                     PChar('Courier New'),
                     @EnumFontsProc,0)  <> 0  then
```

Comment: Doesn't [`EnumFontFamilies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-enumfontfamiliesa) return an integer?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand Thanks for revealing this. In XE3 (I tested with this version) this function is described as BOOL, that is why I used such syntax. It is worth to add remark for newer versions